# Electro-magnetism. What's it all about anyway?

Tags: voltage, electromagnetism, magnetics, physics

Ok, so am new to electronics. I've been looking up various thing like basic theory, schematics, circuit components, logic gates, and the rest. So all of that (on an extremely basic level anyway), I get. One thing I DON'T get however, and it's the only bit of theory I cannot grasp, is electromagnetism.

Now, I found out after hours of research that voltage is the loss of energy, and is measured in J/C (which they should explain when introducing parallel circuits, I actually get why why the voltage in parallel circuits are constant). After that I found out that the electro in electromagnetism is really just voltage, and we all know what magnetism is.  So, voltage repels, magnetism attracts. Their ying and yang, two sides of the same coin.

Now then, what I don't understand is how all this ties in to real life. I get the basic idea... When you wrap coil around iron, why is the magnetism increased about 700 times? Is the voltage then decreased? And if voltage has an opposing force, the resistance, then does magnetism ALSO have an opposing force, and is there a version of current for magnetism?

It all seems very related to gravity and 'anti gravity' by the way. where gravity holds everything together, anti-gravity pulls it a part. Take our sun, for example. It's always exploding but implodes due to gravity. So is there a law like newtons law, where if A exerts a force on B it has an equal and opposite force. What I mean is, is voltage directly proportional to magnetism?

Sorry if I caused confusion through my own confused state of mind. I get voltage and current and how they work and operate, but, magnetism... and then electromagnetism, it's really hard to grasp.

Any clarification would be much obliged, and much needed.

Best wishes,

James

Comment: How is resistance an opposing force to voltage? Also this is a huge question. However, it has a [simple answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations). How's your vector calculus?

Comment: Haven't learned it, but if you'd be so kind to explain, I shall :)

Comment: No really, I will actually go learn calculus just to understand this, i've been stuck on this bit of theory for a month as of now.

Comment: Oh, as for voltage and resistance, voltage is just j/c right? So if you increase resistance your going to increase the voltage right? So aren't they opposing forces. It's like water represents resistance and fire represents voltage.

Comment: Wait, so all else constant, an increase in water leads to an increase in fire? There might be some other fundamentals missing here...

Comment: Most of your question is answerable, but to your question of "why", I suggest you watch this.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMFPe-DwULM

Answer (score 3):

Electricity and magetism are very closely related, and it's not as straightforward relationship as 'electricity attracts' and 'magnetism repels'.  They both can produce 'attractive' and 'repulsive' forces.  Two positive charges repel.  A negative and a positive charge attract.  Two magent 'north' ends repel.  A 'north' and a 'south' magent end attract.  But the really interesting part is that current flowing in a wire produces a magentic field, and changing magentic fields produce electric fields.  The relationship between them is one of derivatives - a changing magnetic field produces an electric field, and a changing electric field produces a magnetic field.

A number of years ago there was an issue of the irregular webcomic that discusses Maxwell's equations, which define the relationship between the electric and the magnetic field: http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/1420.html .  I highly recommend reading it a couple of times.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the article, I read the first paragraph and I think it's going to be a very good read.

Now, time for some vector calculus.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Current flowing in a line creates a circular magnetic field around that line.  If you make current go in a ring, then those magnetic fields from each little portion of the wire add up to make a stronger magnetic field going thru the center of the ring.  The magnetic field lines return by going around the outside of the ring, but since that path is longer they are more spread out and weaker there.

A line of current makes a circular magnetic field, and a circular current makes a straight magnetic field thru the center of the circle.  That field is proportional to the current around the ring.

What all those windings of a electromagnet do is make it look like there is a much stronger current flowing around the ring.  One loop of wire with 1 A flowing thru it doesn't make much of a magnetic field.  You wouldn't be able to pick up a paper clip with it, for example.  However, 1 A thru 200 windings is like 200 A flowing around a ring.  That can pick up a paper clip, especially if you put something in the middle, like iron or ferrite, that has high "magnetic conductivity" (the phancy word is permiability) so that the field lines try to go thru it as much as possible.  If that is something like a iron bolt, then the field will be particularly concentrated at the ends of the bolt.

That was not a very scientific description.  You can look those up in lots of places.  I am more trying to give you some intuition for how this all works.

Comment: Ah, so, I guess you could say there is a relationship between the distant current travels and magnetism (at nay given account).

See, that's interesting, I thought it was increase voltage = increase magnetism, but apparently it's not so straight forward.

Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: It's not voltage, it's charges in motion.  Voltage will 'push' the charges along, but the moving charges are what actually generates the magnetic field when you have flowing current.